# Service Fabric service with WCF communication deployment

Tags: c#, wcf, deployment, cloud, azure-service-fabric

Here is a simple Service Fabric stateless service with WCF communication and it's client - a console app. It works well on the local cluster, client gets responce from the service. But I don't know how to communicate with a service if I deploy it in the cloud. What should I do to access it from console app?

**SF Stateless service with WCF communications:**

Contract:

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPresidentialService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Task<string> GetInfo();
    }
```

Service:

```
internal sealed class PresidentialService : StatelessService, IPresidentialService
{
    public PresidentialService(StatelessServiceContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public Task<string> GetInfo() => Task.FromResult($"Node {Context.NodeContext.NodeName} operating");

    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(context =>
                new WcfCommunicationListener<IPresidentialService>(wcfServiceObject: this, serviceContext: context,
                    endpointResourceName: "WcfServiceEndpoint",
                    listenerBinding: WcfUtility.CreateTcpListenerBinding()))
        };
    }
}
```

}

**Client console app:**

WCF client:

```
public class PresidentialServiceClient : ServicePartitionClient<WcfCommunicationClient<IPresidentialService>>
    {
        public PresidentialServiceClient(
            ICommunicationClientFactory<WcfCommunicationClient<IPresidentialService>> communicationClientFactory,
            Uri serviceUri, ServicePartitionKey partitionKey = null,
            TargetReplicaSelector targetReplicaSelector = TargetReplicaSelector.Default, string listenerName = null,
            OperationRetrySettings retrySettings = null) : base(communicationClientFactory, serviceUri, partitionKey,
            targetReplicaSelector, listenerName, retrySettings)
        {
        }

        public Task<string> GetInfo() => InvokeWithRetryAsync(client => client.Channel.GetInfo());
    }
```

Client App:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var binding = WcfUtility.CreateTcpClientBinding();
            var partitionResolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();
            var wcfClientFactory =
                new WcfCommunicationClientFactory<IPresidentialService>(binding,
                    servicePartitionResolver: partitionResolver);
            var serviceUri = new Uri("fabric:/Application5/PresidentialService");
            var client = new PresidentialServiceClient(wcfClientFactory, serviceUri, ServicePartitionKey.Singleton);
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(client.GetInfo().Result);
                Console.ReadKey();
            } while (true);
        }
```

Added to `ServiceManifest.xml`:

```
<Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Name="WcfServiceEndpoint" />
</Endpoints>
```

**UPDATE**

Changed `ServicePartitionResolver`:

```
var partitionResolver = new ServicePartitionResolver("sfapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19000");
```

Still not works.

**UPDATE**

Added a load balancer rule for TCP port 777.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the service is running in the cloud, you can't use the default resolver.

> The default ServicePartitionResolver assumes that the client is
>   running in same cluster as the service. If that is not the case,
>   create a ServicePartitionResolver object and pass in the cluster
>   connection endpoints.

Try [something](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication.md) like

```
ServicePartitionResolver resolver = new ServicePartitionResolver("mycluster.cloudapp.azure.com:19000");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf

Comment: please provide an example how to use another resolver.

Comment: are you using a secure cluster? if so, you'll need to provide credentials.

Comment: No, cluster is unsecured.

Comment: At which port is the service running, did you open that in the load balancer?

Comment: Yep, TCP port 777. Should I change endpoint in `ServiceManifest.xls` like this: `<Endpoint Name="WcfServiceEndpoint" Protocol="tcp"  Port="777" />`?

Comment: Still no success. Console application freezes at line `Console.WriteLine(client.GetInfo().Result);`, no exception thrown.

Comment: I'm facing similar problem, tried changing servicepartitionresolver, added port rule in LB, still no luck. how did you solve this?